# Parsing double value from String in Java

Tags: java

I am supposed to extract the double values from the following string:

```
r ( 4.5, 1.0 ) 10.5 7 ;
```

However my code deletes everything but the digits and that's not what I want.
My code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class mine {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

      String str;
      String numbers;

      Scanner SC=new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter string that contains numbers: ");
      str=SC.nextLine();

      //extracting string
      numbers=str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

      System.out.println("Numbers are: " + numbers);
    }
}
```

Output of my code:

```
Enter string that contains numbers: r ( 4.5, 1.0 ) 10.5 7 
Numbers are: 45101057
```

I want to find a way to assign the numbers to variable. So for example using the following string: `r ( 4.5, 1.0 ) 10.5 7` (Assuming a,b,c,d are already declared)
I want this:

```
a = 4.5
b = 1.0
c = 10.5 
d = 7
```

Comment: This question is somewhat ill-formed. How exactly will your input look like? Is `(( 2.0, 42, 7), 13) 36` a valid input? is `.3` valid? is some String, representing a number unrepresentable in `float` or `double` a valid input? How should this unrepresentable number be preseneted (flooring, ceiling, nearest value)?...

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep floating-point numbers and separators, you must include dot character and space, in addition to decimal digits, into the replacement regex:

```
numbers = str.replaceAll("[^0-9. ]", "");
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/ve0LnB)

Once you have the string, separating out the individual numbers can be done using the technique discussed in this Q&A: [Convert a string of numbers into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7781038/335858).

Answer (score 0):

Having variables in that fashion is only going to be useful if you're *guaranteed* that you have four values in your file.  For flexibility's sake, it's better to place this in a list instead.

```
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
// assuming str already has the numbers...
for(String s : str.split(" ") {
    numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
}
```

Declaring these as individual variables uses 99% of the same approach above, just swapping out a list for the individual values.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it uses a second scanner to try to parse each token as a Double; if it's not a double, the parsing will fail):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter string that contains numbers: ");
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    Scanner token = new Scanner(str);
    while token.hasNext() {
         String tokenStr = token.next();
         try {
             double d = Double.parseDouble(tokenStr);
             // YOUR CODE: do something with d here, such as appending
             // it to an array, assigning it to a var, or printing it out.

         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
             // no op
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works except for example if the input is : "r ( 4.5, 1.0 ) 10.5 7" ;  It doesn't read the 4.5 because of the comma.

Comment: Well, I'd argue that "4.5," isn't a number and shouldn't be recognized as one. How do you want to handle things such as "4x5" (should this give 2 numbers, or 0)? Are the characters to ignore only on the ends of each token?